# Cascading delete rows from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, cascading-deletes

I've got two tables with the following structure:

Person

- Id
- Name

Class

- Id
- PersonId
- Sequence

and some data:

Person

```
1   name1
2   name2
3   name3
```

Class

```
1   1   3
2   1   1
3   1   2
4   2   1
```

`Class` table can contain multiple rows related to one row from `Person`. `PersonId` from `Class` table is foreign key to `Id` in `Person` table. I'd like to delete data related to `Person` with `Id` 1, so remove the 3 rows from `Class`, and 1 row from `Person` using one query.

How can I do that in SQL?

Comment: Under "foreign-key relationships" change "Insert and Update specification" to `Delete Rule: Cascade`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175493.aspx Then delete from `Person` which also deletes from `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NULL,
    [Sequence] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Person]    Script Date: 26-05-2014 07:54:26 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Person] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Class]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Class_Person] FOREIGN KEY([PersonId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Class] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Class_Person]
GO
```